# Can't use the get mothod on my Future parameter to get result of thread with the callable interface

Tags: java, multithreading, future, callable

I am trying to build a multithreading app that can calculate prime numbers (calculations done in another class), by using the methods of the other class via threadings, I need to then pass the result to the other class in order to print the results.

My issue is, my callable thread should be returning a list type, so when I try to use futures.get(), the compiler doesn't recognize my type of data

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);

Callable<List<Long>> callableTask = () -> {

            List<Long> myLis = new ArrayList<>();
            try
            {

                PrimeComputerTester pct = new PrimeComputerTester() 
                Method meth = PrimeComputerTester.class.getDeclaredMethod("getPrimes",long.class);
                meth.setAccessible(true);

                myLis = (List<Long>) meth.invoke(pct, max);


                //System.out.println("List of prime numbers: ");
                //for(int i = 0; i < myLis.size(); i++)
                 //  System.out.println(myLis.get(i));

            }catch (Exception e) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
                System.out.println(" interrupted");
            }

    return myLis;  //the thread should be returning myList
};


//using the list<Long> type for my callable interface

List<Callable<List<Long>>> callableTasks = new ArrayList<>();

//creating a tasked thread
callableTasks.add(callableTask);



  try {
      List<Future<List<Long>>> futures = executor.invokeAll(callableTasks);

      List<Long> results = new ArrayList<>();

      results.add(futures.get());   //This line doesn't work

      //System.out.println("List of prime numbers 2 : "+futures.get());
       for(int i = 0; i < futures.size(); i++)
                   System.out.println(futures.get(i));
     executor.shutdown();
     //   System.out.println(" interrupted");


  } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
      Logger.getLogger(PrimeComputer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
  }
```

expected result:
    results.add(futures.get());
should be working

But instead, I can't use futures.get()

Upon compilation, I get the following error:

```
 method get int interface Liste <E> cannot be applied to given types;

 required int

 found: no arguments

 reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
 where E is a type-variable:
 E extends Object declared in interface List
```

Comment: what do you mean by ”this line does not work“? does not compile or throws exception? what is the diagnostics?

Comment: @AlexeiKaigorodov  I've just edited the output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this line is invalid `futures.get()`, basically it is an `List<Future<List<Long>>> futures` list of `Future` object.

So First you need to get the `Future`object from list, and then you need to get the value `List<Long>` from `Future` object

```
Future<List<Long>> f = futures.get(0);   // get the object at index 1 if list is empty then you will get NullPointerExeception
results.addAll(f.get());
```

Or loop the list or iterator the list

```
for(Future<List<Long>> f : futures){
      results.addAll(f.get());
   }
```

Comment: Thank you so much, spent at least 3 hours trying to debug, BTW the correct answer shoud be:

 Future<List<Long>> f = futures.get(0);

As 0 is the first element of the list, 1 throws an out of boundry exception.

I've also used instead of what you've pruposed in order to iterate throught it more easily
 results = f.get();